# How to escape $ on Sublime Text Snippet

Tags: php, sublimetext3, sublimetext, code-snippets

I create a snippet for my PHP laravel in SBT3

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
dd("${1}",${1});
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>dd</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

When I typed `dd`

I see this now.

[image]

if I type more

[image]

notice it's wrong ?

It need have the `$` like this

```
dd("nameofTheVariable",$nameofTheVariable);
```

How do I modify my snippet to escape the `$`?

Comment: I don't have Sublime Text installed at the moment so I can't verify it, but try adding the dollar sign escaped: `dd("${1}",\$${1});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nameofTheVariable` is stored in `${1}`, so you'll need to add another `$` before it.

Use a backslash (`\`) to escape it: `dd("${1}",\$${1});`

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
dd("${1}", \$${1});
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>dd</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

---

[image: Output]

<sup>**Note**: I've placed a space ( ) after the comma (`,`) as [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#44-method-arguments) prefers it.</sup>